# Some questions to help me to be sure to understand mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Good day everyone,
I have some questions about the mutex (the subject is already specific). So, I need to be sure to not have missconceptions ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex )  :

1) I would like to be sure that a std::mutex cannot be shared between 2 threads at the same time. Is it true ?

2) What happens , if randomly, two independant threads ask the mutex at the same time ?

3) According to my understanding, when a thread takes the mutex, it prevents any other thread to modify at the same time the global variables.   Is it a good understanding ?

Could you correct if for any of those questions, I am not right ?

I would be thankful to you.

Comment: Yes. Doesn't happen. Yes.

Comment: 1) yes. Check out shared_mutex as well.
2) the mutex handles it, you shouldn't worry about that
3) any code with the mutex taken cannot be simultaneously executed by another thread until the mutex is released

Comment: @super, When a thread "takes the mutex," that absolutely _does not_ prevent other threads from "modify at the same time the global variabls." It doesn't prevent _anything_ other than preventing other threads from "taking" the same mutex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should probably read a bit further about mutex (mutexes? mutices?), because it is not just a concept of c++, but of computer science in general. To answer your questions:

1. Yes, it's true, that's the whole point about a mutex. At any point in time only one thread can own the mutex lock.
2. One of the threads will get the mutex, the other won't. The implementation will take care of this, even if the access is happening on mulitple physical cores at the same physical time.
3. Not quite, you can always choose to ignore the mutex and still change those variables. It is up to you how you solve concurrency problems.

## Edit

I think some languages provide containers that wrap variables in such a way that they are only readable by one thread at a time. I think they are called Monitors in Java.

## General concept:

```
std::mutex m;
int globalVar;

void foo()
{
//Acquire lock or wait, if another thread already acquired the lock.
mutex.lock();
//At any given time this code will be executed by one thread only (or none)
globalVar = bar();
mutex.unlock();
}

//However you can choose to ignore the mutex...
void evilFoo()
{
  //This can be executed by multiple threads at the same time (even parallel to foo())
  globalVar = bar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) It **should** be shared. How otherwise you will use it???

Edit: Ok, it seems that question is somewhat misleading. What do you mean by "shared" in this case?

Edit2: If by "shared" you mean that one mutex can be held by more than one thread, then answer is: this can't happen.

2) Even if it happen exactly at same physical time on two different cores there will be some arbitrating mechanism that will give mutex to one or other thread.

3) No. When *other* thread takes mutex you **know** that you can't modify variables protected by this mutex without consequences, and should write code such that there will be no such modifications. But mutex itself in no any way **prevents** such modifications. And of course you shouldn't read such variables without holding mutex also.

Comment: I think with 'shared' he means, that two threads can acquire the lock for one mutex at the same time. At least I understand it in this way.

Comment: @churill : you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let assume Alice gives 5 things to Bob. You will have code like.

```
alice -= 5;
bob +=5;
```

We do not want a situation to arise where we remove 5 from Alice but have not given the five to Bob.

`std::thread` uses the operating system support for pre-emptive multithreading. This means the operating may interrupt a thread at any point in time and schedule anther. On multi-core machines, they may even run concurrently. This means a thread might see inconsistent data.

A Mutex is an operating system object whose job it is to ensure that only a single thread can access a critical section of code at a time.

So when thread 1 enters the mutex, it increments the mutex's access count. When the next thread tries to enter the mutex it detects that the access count is not zero. The operating system then suspends the thread.

When the first thread releases the mutex, the other threads then become runnable again. This means the operating system may schedule them to run now or a bit later depending on its priority.

The newly runnable thread may then attempt to enter the mutex with the same rules applied as above.

This means that provided a common mutex is used, no two threads may enter code protected by the mutex at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

1) They can be shared but the mutex is used to prevent simultaneous access from threads , to the resources you want to be accessed and modified only by one thread at once.

2) The semantics of a mutex are that two threads cannot lock the same mutex at the same time.

3) The mutex  prevents any other thread to modify at the same time the resources that are processed after the lock of the mutex, until you unlock the mutex. The global variables are one of them.

Comment: Locking a mutex only prevents one thing: It prevents other threads from locking the same mutex. It does not prevent anything else. If the developer wants to prevent other threads from using some resource when the mutex is locked, then it is entirely the developer's responsibility to write the code for those threads so that they will behave in that way.

Comment: Thank you Solomon for your help here and for your help in my other question

Comment: @Solomon Slow yes true, I just gave an example of use, that is common, of mutexes.